# Summarizing data with na.rm = TRUE

Tags: r, date, dplyr, na, lubridate

Consider the following example that summarizes a data frame using `dplyr`'s `summarise` pipe to identify the `min`imum `DATE` associated with some `CHAR`:

```
library('tidyverse')
library('lubridate')

temp <- data.frame(
  CHAR = c(
    'A',
    'B',
    'C'
  ),
  DATE = c(
    '20090101',
    '20100101',
    NA
  ) %>% ymd(), # Turn character strings to dates
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
) %>% group_by(
  CHAR
) %>% summarise(
  DATE = min(DATE, na.rm = TRUE) # Extract minimum date
) %>% ungroup()
```

Identifying whether the `min`imum is `NA` or not is tested using `is.na`:

```
temp %>% mutate(
  DATE_lgl = DATE %>% is.na() # Identify dates that are missing/NA
)
```

The output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  CHAR  DATE       DATE_lgl
  <chr> <date>     <lgl>   
1 A     2009-01-01 FALSE   
2 B     2010-01-01 FALSE   
3 C     NA         FALSE
```

incorrectly has `DATE_lgl` showing `FALSE` where `DATE` is `NA`. Why is that?

Removing `na.rm = TRUE` fixes the issue, but doesn't work with the following configuration where `na.rm = TRUE` is needed to eliminate missing entries:

```
temp <- data.frame(
  CHAR = c(
    'A',
    'B',
    'C',
    'C'
  ),
  DATE = c(
    '20090101',
    '20100101',
    NA,
    '20110101'
  ) %>% ymd(), # Turn character strings to dates
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
) %>% group_by(
  CHAR
) %>% summarise(
  DATE = min(DATE, na.rm = TRUE) # Extract minimum date
) %>% ungroup()
```

---

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Canada.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Canada.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_Canada.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=English_Canada.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] bindrcpp_0.2.2  lubridate_1.7.4 forcats_0.3.0   stringr_1.3.1   dplyr_0.7.5     purrr_0.2.5    
 [7] readr_1.1.1     tidyr_0.8.1     tibble_1.4.2    ggplot2_2.2.1   tidyverse_1.2.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.17     cellranger_1.1.0 pillar_1.2.3     compiler_3.5.0   plyr_1.8.4       bindr_0.1.1     
 [7] tools_3.5.0      jsonlite_1.5     nlme_3.1-137     gtable_0.2.0     lattice_0.20-35  pkgconfig_2.0.1 
[13] rlang_0.2.1      psych_1.8.4      cli_1.0.0        rstudioapi_0.7   yaml_2.1.19      parallel_3.5.0  
[19] haven_1.1.1      xml2_1.2.0       httr_1.3.1       hms_0.4.2        grid_3.5.0       tidyselect_0.2.4
[25] glue_1.2.0       R6_2.2.2         readxl_1.1.0     foreign_0.8-70   modelr_0.1.2     reshape2_1.4.3  
[31] magrittr_1.5     scales_0.5.0     rvest_0.3.2      assertthat_0.2.0 mnormt_1.5-5     colorspace_1.3-2
[37] utf8_1.1.4       stringi_1.1.7    lazyeval_0.2.1   munsell_0.4.3    broom_0.4.4      crayon_1.3.4
```

Comment: `dput(temp$DATE[3])` reveals the issue: `structure(Inf, class = "Date")`

Comment: Could this be an issue with `lubridate`?

Comment: Although I developed a workaround, I am not still fully aware of the cause of this issue. I tried to replace the `ymd` function with `as.Date`, and the issue is the same, so I think it is not a lubridate specific question. CPak's point is great. It could be some limitations of the `date` class that does not have an associated NA for the Inf from the numeric class. However, this is just my guess. Thanks for sharing this interesting question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is you are evaluating

```
min(NA, na.rm=TRUE)
# Inf
```

for row 3, which leads to it being

```
dput(temp$DATE[3])
# structure(Inf, class = "Date")
```

Add `is.finite` to your `mutate`

```
temp %>% 
   mutate(DATE_lgl = is.finite(DATE) | is.na(DATE)  # Identify dates that are missing/NA)

 # A tibble: 3 x 3
 #   CHAR  DATE       DATE_lgl
 #  <chr> <date>     <lgl>   
 # 1 A     2009-01-01 TRUE    
 # 2 B     2010-01-01 TRUE    
 # 3 C     NA         FALSE
```

Printing `NA` is likely a printing limitation of Date class

```
as.Date(Inf, origin="1970-01-01")
# NA
dput(as.Date(Inf, origin="1970-01-01"))
# structure(Inf, class = "Date")
```

Comment: The output still points to being `NA` though. So is `NA` in class `Date` equivalent to `Inf` and therefore not truly `NA`?

Answer (score 2):

A workaround is to convert the `Date` column to character and then evaluate if it is `NA`.

```
temp %>% mutate(
  DATE_lgl = is.na(as.character(DATE))
)

# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#   CHAR  DATE       DATE_lgl
#   <chr> <date>     <lgl>   
# 1 A     2009-01-01 FALSE   
# 2 B     2010-01-01 FALSE   
# 3 C     NA         TRUE
```